# solve maximum product of three array elements without sorting

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

There is a variety of answers for the MaxProductOfThree task on [codility.com](https://codility.com/), most of them involving a sorting algorithm.

The problem is:

A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.

The problem is to find the maximum product of 3 elements from given array.

The length of the array is between 3 and 100,000

each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000..1,000]

```
    expected worst-case time complexity is O(N*log(N));

    expected worst-case space complexity is O(1),
```

beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
Example:

```
  a[0] = -3;
  a[1] = 7;
  a[2] = 2;
  a[3] = 1;
  a[4] = 5;
  a[5] = 7;
```

the max product is a[1]*a[4]*a[5] = 245

Is there a linear-time solution to this problem, besides the O(n log n) approach that involves sorting?

Comment: Please describe the question better, what is the input and what is the expected output. example will be great.

Comment: If you just need to find the 3 largest elements in the array, yes that's possible in O(n): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: I have the answer too but I need to wait 8 hours to post it because i am a new member. The method get the max product of 3 consists in basically find the biggest 3 numbers from the array and the smallest 2 numbers from the array in just 1 iteration over the array. I'll post the code answer after 8 hours properly commented of course

Comment: @DanutClapa If you already have the answer, why did you post the question on SO?

Comment: @DanutClapa If I remember correctly, there is a checkbox in the question form where it says "answer this question yourself", which allows you to publish both the question and answer at the same time. By the way, your question is not held to lower standards just because you plan to answer it yourself. You have to stick to SO guidelines, and your question is lacking quality. For example at the very least you should include or paraphrase the problem statement.

Comment: @ Abhishek Bansal because i want to spread the knowledge. I've seen a lot of answers but none with minimal steps. @ Niklas B yes there it is but the system don't allow me to put the answer earlier than 8 hours.

Comment: So 8 hours passed and you down-voted the question, how i can put the answer?

Comment: @DanutClapa the question was put on hold for being unclear.  It's not clear what it asks. As I said, the fact that you plan to write an answer yourself does not mean that question does not have to be good. For example,  you forgot to *describe the problem* you are trying to solve

Comment: @Niklas B the description of the problem is on codility.com as is written in the question title. what more clarifications do you need to be a clear question?

Comment: @DanutClapa Imagine codility.com gets bankrupt tomorrow and shuts down their webpage. Is your question still self-contained? Stack Overflow is made for eternity :)

Comment: @Niklas B :) you are funny :). this is kinda trivial but is a life lesson for you and for me (its a Romanian joke) An old woman in a buss is seen by the inspector using 2 tickets to take the buss. The inspector ask she why is doing that because isn't necessary, the old women says: this is to get assured if i loose 1 ticket i still have 1 more. Inspector ask again but if you loose the second 1 too? The old woman say then in that case i have subscription ... :) Any way for your satisfaction ill just copy paste the question from codility along with my restriction comments for the solution.

Comment: @DanutClapa I was serious. *Every time you link to an external resource* on Stack Overflow, [you are supposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way) to summarize its contents so that your post is still valid if the link goes dead. It is much more unlikely that *both* SO and the other site go down than just one of them. In this case you did not even link to the problem, which is worse. Maybe if you edit your question and make it fit the guidelines, we can try to reopen it

Comment: @Niklas B The question is written in clear now, you don't even need to go on codility.com to read it.

Comment: I noticed,  reversed my vote and voted for reopen.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
/*    The method get the max product of 3 consists in basically find the biggest 3 numbers from the array and the smallest 2 numbers from the array in just 1 iteration over the array. Here is the java code:*/

    int solution(int[] a) {
/* the minimums initialized with max int to avoid cases with extreme max in array and false minims 0 minimums returned */

        int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
/* the same logic for maximum initializations but of course inverted to avoid extreme minimum values in array and false 0 maximums */

        int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int max3 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

//the iteration over the array

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

//test if max1 is smaller than current array value

            if (a[i] > max1) {
            //if a[i] is greater than the biggest max then a chain reaction is started,
            // max3 will be max2, max2 will be actual max1 and max1 will be a[i]    
                max3=max2;
                max2=max1;
                max1=a[i];
/* in case if current a[i] isn't bigger than max1 we test it to see maybe is bigger than second
 max. Then the same logic from above is applied for the max2 amd max3 */

            }else if(a[i]>max2){
                max3 = max2;
                max2 = a[i];
/* finally if current array value isn't bigger than max1 and max2 maybe is greater than max3 */

            }else if(a[i]>max3){
                max3 = a[i];
            }

/* The logic from above with maximums is is applied here with minimums but of course inverted to
discover the 2 minimums from current array. */

            if (a[i] < min1) {
                min2 =min1;
                min1=a[i];
            } else if (a[i] < min2) {
                min2 = a[i];
            }
        }
/* after we discovered the 3 greatest maximums and the 2 smallest minimums from the array
we do the 2 products of 3 from the greatest maximum and the 2 minimums . This is necessary
because mathematically the product of 2 negative values is a positive value, and because of
this the product of min1 * min2 * max1 can be greater than max1 * max2 * max3
 and the product built from the the 3 maximums. */

        int prod1 = min1 * min2 * max1;
        int prod2 = max1 * max2 * max3;

//here we just return the biggest product

        return prod1 > prod2 ? prod1 : prod2;

    }
```

Comment: I solved it in a similar way, but you need to consider the input of negative only numbers e.g. [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]. With this solution the complexity is even O(N)

Comment: i am taking in the consideration the arrays with negatives numbers only. So, if you take a look the 3 greatest numbers from that array is -1, -2, -3 fall in the case of the 3 greatest maximums and their product is a negative one but still the greatest product.

Answer (score 17):

There are only two possible options for the max product in a sorted array.

1) The largest (the last) three elements

2) Combination of two smallest and the largest elements (in case of negative elements, a product of two negatives is positive which multiplied with the largest element, if positive, of an array can produce the largest product)

So the solution is a max of the two and nothing else. The below got 100/100 on Codility.

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
// import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {

    public int solution(int[] A) {

        int N = A.length;
        Arrays.sort(A);

        /**
         * When we sort an array there are two possible options for the largest product
         * 1) The largest (the last) three elements
         * 2) Combination of two smallest and the largest elements
         * Logic of (1): Obvious
         * Logic of (2): A pair of negatives multiplied returns a positive, which in combination with 
         * the largest positive element of the array can give the max outcome.
         * Therefore we return the max of options (1) and (2)
         */
        return Math.max(A[0] * A[1] * A[N - 1], A[N - 1] * A[N - 2] * A[N - 3]);
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Title and body of the question ask about `without sorting`.

Comment: It's true that the question specified no sorting.  However this Codility exercise is in their chapter on Sorting.  And man, if there's a 100% solution out there in three lines of code, I'm all for it!  Fantastic!

Comment: Got the same idea with you! Hold my beer =))

Answer (score 3):

**Kotlin without sorting.**

I wonder why so many answer here ignore the question title "without sorting"!

```
    fun solution(A: IntArray): Int {
        // write your code in Kotlin
        if (A.size < 3) return -1

        var max1: Int = Int.MIN_VALUE
        var max2: Int = Int.MIN_VALUE
        var max3: Int = Int.MIN_VALUE
        var min1: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE
        var min2: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE

        A.forEach {
            when {
                it > max1 -> {
                    max3 = max2
                    max2 = max1
                    max1 = it
                }
                it > max2 -> {
                    max3 = max2
                    max2 = it
                }
                it > max3 -> {
                    max3 = it
                }
            }

            when {
                it < min1 -> {
                    min2 = min1
                    min1 = it
                }
                it < min2 -> {
                    min2 = it
                }
            }
        }

        return (min1 * min2 * max1).coerceAtLeast(max1 * max2 * max3)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an O(n log n ) solution.
First we sort the array,
then knowing that two negatives with great value make a bigger positive we need to calculate the max at the left of the array, and the product of the 3 elements that are to the right of the array and compare which one is bigger.

Here's a sample code:

```
// [1,2,3,4] = 24
  public int solution(int[] sortedArray) {
       Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
       int length = sortedArray.length;
       int  P, Q, R;
       int maximumLeft = Integer.MIN_VALUE, maximumRight = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

       P = sortedArray[length - 3];
       Q = sortedArray[length - 2];
       R = sortedArray[length - 1];
       maximumRight = P * Q * R;

       P = sortedArray[0];
       Q = sortedArray[1];
       R = sortedArray[length -1];

       maximumLeft = P * Q * R;


       return maximumRight > maximumLeft ? maximumRight : maximumLeft;
   }
```

Don't forget to import java.util.Arrays;
See this link for the [Java](https://github.com/moxi/codility-lessons/blob/master/Codility/Sorting/MaxProductOfThree.java) file.

Comment: yes, but is O(n log n) and this is the standard way to do that. But can we do better? And the answer is YES. take a look at my solution is O (n).

Comment: Yes, you're solution is better in terms of time :), I like it!!

Comment: thank you :) , your solution is correct and neat also. But is a little less efficient :).

Comment: Shorter version: Shorter version: Arrays.sort(A); return Math.max(A[0]*A[1]*A[A.length-1], A[A.length-1]*A[A.length-2]*A[A.length-3]);

Comment: One quibble. . . you call one variable maximumLeft, but it really isn't that. It's the two smallest plus the biggest.  It takes some study to see that you're actually taking the same approach that others here are using. Using a different variable name, like tryTwoNegatives, would have made it more clear.

Comment: Good observation, when dealing with arrays I tend to form a graphical representation of a "number line" where negative numbers go to the left and positive numbers to the right, your comment is accurate since is using the two far left numbers multiplied by the most right number (max), in essence making it to not be just left numbers. Perhaps, maximumProductUsingLeftNumbers and maximumProductUsingRightNumbers would have been more accurate but also more verbose. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go it doesn't use sorting and still gets 100%.

[image]

```
#include<limits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    //Keep the absolute value for max 2 -ve num . As their mul will be +ve
    int abs1 = numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int abs2 = numeric_limits<int>::min();

    //Keep the max three num irrespective of sign
    int max1 = numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int max2 = numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int max3 = numeric_limits<int>::min();

    unsigned int size = A.size()-1;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= size ; ++i) {
        if(A[i] > 0 ){

        } else if(abs(A[i]) >= abs1 ) {
            abs2 = abs1;
            abs1 = abs(A[i]);
        }else if(abs(A[i]) >= abs2 ) {
            abs2 = abs(A[i]);
        }

        if(A[i] >= max1 ){
            //Push max1s prev value to max2 and max2's prev val to max3
            max3 = max2;
            max2 = max1;
            max1 = A[i];
        } else if(A[i] >= max2 ) {
            max3 = max2;
            max2 = A[i];
        }else if(A[i] > max3 ) {
            max3 = A[i];
        }
    }
    // Either max 3 multiplication , or Max 2 negative num whose mul is +ve and the regular max
    return max(max1 * max2 * max3, abs1 * abs2 * max1);
}


int main(){
    vector<int> test = {-3, 1, 2, -2, 5, 6};
    cout << solution(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of great answers, but I think this one has some elegance in it, also gives [100% on codility](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingY8RGQQ-ZJD/).

---

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
    Arrays.sort(A);
    int F = 0, L = A.length - 1;
    int s1 = A[F] * A[F + 1] * A[F + 2];
    int s2 = A[F] * A[F + 1] * A[L];
    int s3 = A[F] * A[L - 1] * A[L];
    int s4 = A[L - 2] * A[L - 1] * A[L];
    return Math.max(Math.max(s1, s2), Math.max(s3, s4));
}
```

---

Comment: Actually `s1`, and `s3 `will pretty much never be the largest. Unless `A.length = 3;` But in that case you have `s1 = s2 = s3 = s4` :)
So you only need `return Math.max(s2, s4)+;` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Here, is my solution, I have sorted only upto required one
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training68T6KT-NY6/

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    int result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < A.length; j++) {
            if (A[i] < A[j]) {
                int temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.length - i; j++) {
            if (A[A.length - 1 - i] > A[j]) {
                int temp = A[A.length - 1 - i];
                A[A.length - 1 - i] = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
            }
        }

    }
    if ((A[A.length - 1] < 0) && A[A.length - 1] * A[A.length - 2] > 0) {

        result = A[0] * A[A.length - 1] * A[A.length - 2];
        if (result > A[0] * A[1] * A[2])
            return result;
    }
    return A[0] * A[1] * A[2];
}
```

Comment: Performance and memory usage could be improved by using pre instead of post incement/decrement!

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
int solution(vector<int>& A) {
    // write your code in C++14 (g++ 6.2.0)
    int missing = 1;
    vector<int> count(A.size());

    for (int n = 0; n < A.size(); n++) {
        if (A[n] > 0 && A[n] < (A.size() + 1)) {
            count[A[n] - 1]++;
        }
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < A.size(); n++) {
        if (count[n] == 0) {
            break;
        }

        missing++;
    }

    return missing;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python solution - 100%

```
def solution(A): 
    A.sort() 
    return max(A[0] * A[1] * A[-1] , A[-3] * A[-2] * A[-1])
```

Comment: If your solution concern python, it's off-topic because the question have the java tag

Comment: Squarely fails `without sorting`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int[] rev(int[] validData) {
    for (int i = 0; i < validData.length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = validData[i];
        validData[i] = validData[validData.length - i - 1];
        validData[validData.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return validData;
}

public static int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    long p = 0, q = 0, r = 0, max1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE, res = 0;

    Arrays.sort(A);
    A = rev(A);
    int start = 0, end = A.length;

        //upper bound
        p = A[start];
        q = A[start + 1];
        r = A[start + 2];
        max1 = p * q * r;


        //lower bound

        q = A[end - 1];
        r = A[end - 2];
        max2 = p * q * r;


    return (int) Math.max(max1, max2);
}
```

kinda late, but this approach is less efficient, but still fast. it reverses the array, then the logic is , the upper bound is the first element * two consectives, or either first element * two last consecutives, either one of the two should yield the maximaum.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution applied to the problem got 100%.

```
import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        int length = A.length;
        int max =0;
        if(A[0]>0||A[length-1]<0){
            max = (A[length-1]*A[length-2]*A[length-3]);
            return max;
        }else{
            int lastMultiPlier = A[length-1];
            if((A[0]*A[1])>(A[length-2]*A[length-3])){
                max=A[0]*A[1]*lastMultiPlier;
            }else{
                max=A[length-2]*A[length-3]*lastMultiPlier;
            }
            return max;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to use sorting in the Codility problem. here is a solution that gives you 100%. Without sorting it becomes messy but definitely possible.

[image]

```
#include<limits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    int abs1 = numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int abs2 = numeric_limits<int>::min();
    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    unsigned int size = A.size()-1;
    int temp;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= size ; ++i) {
        if(A[i] > 0 ) continue;
        if(abs(A[i]) >= abs1 ) {
            temp = abs1;
            abs1 = abs(A[i]);
            abs2 = temp;
        }else if(abs(A[i]) >= abs2 ) {
            abs2 = abs(A[i]);
        }
    }
    return max(A[size] * A[size-1] * A[size-2], abs1 * abs2 * A[size]);
}


int main(){
    vector<int> test = {-4, -6, 3, 4, 5};
    cout << solution(test);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4):

```
function solution(A) {
     // first we order it
     A.sort((a, b) => (a - b));

     // we see the first two possibilities and we compare them        
     let val1 = A[A.length - 1] * A[A.length - 2] * A[A.length - 3]

     let val2 = A[A.length - 1] * A[0] * A[1]

     // we return the higher value
     if (val1 > val2) { return val1 } else { return val2 }
}
```

Comment: Please note that Node.js 8 is out of its maintenance window and is no longing receiving support. You should transition to Node.js 12 or 13.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

python 3, thank you DanutClapa, I did first the positives well but your clarification on last 2 negatives was the solution.

```
def solution(arr):

    if not arr:
        return 0

    if len(arr) == 3:
        m   = 1
        for i in arr:
            m *= i
        return m
    else:
        max_num       = min(arr)
        second_max    = min(arr)
        tercero_max   = min(arr)

        min_num       = max(arr)
        min_num_2     = max(arr)

        for i in range(0, len(arr)):

            if (arr[i] > max_num):
                tercero_max = second_max
                second_max  = max_num
                max_num     = arr[i]
            elif arr[i] > second_max:
                tercero_max = second_max
                second_max  = arr[i]
            elif arr[i] > tercero_max:
                tercero_max = arr[i]

            if arr[i] < min_num:
                min_num_2 = min_num
                min_num   = arr[i]
            elif arr[i] < min_num_2:
                min_num_2 = arr[i]

        return max( max_num * second_max * tercero_max,     max_num * min_num * min_num_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

No sort ... ES6, but honestly: why no sort?

0. find the biggest number {max[0] > max[1] > max[2]}
1. find the 2 smallest {min[0] < min[1]} (explained above as 2 negative number)
2. return max of [max[0] * max[1] * max[0], max[0] * max[1] * max[2]]

```
function answer(A) {
  maxA = [...A]
  minA = [...A]
  max = [];
  min = [];

  max.push(Math.max(...maxA)); maxA.pop()
  max.push(Math.max(...maxA)); maxA.pop()
  max.push(Math.max(...maxA));
  
  min.push(Math.min(...minA)); minA.pop()
  min.push(Math.min(...minA))

  return Math.max(max[0] * max[1] * max[0], max[0] * max[1] * max[2])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my c# solution. First order the array, for max product max integers required.
For negative integers we need to look first two element of sorted array.
This solution gets 100%

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{ 
    var sorted = A.ToList(); 
    sorted.Sort(); 

    var last = sorted[sorted.Count-1]*sorted[sorted.Count-2]*sorted[sorted.Count-3];
    var firsttwo = sorted[0]*sorted[1]*sorted[sorted.Count-1];

    return Math.Max(last,firsttwo);
}
```

Comment: it should be java

Comment: Yeah I know, it is c# very similar.

Comment: So try to rewrite it to java

Comment: Here is java equivalent:
    public int solution(int[] A)
    {
        Arrays.sort(A);

        var last = A[A.length-1]*A[A.length-2]*A[A.length-3];
        var firsttwo = A[0]*A[1]*A[A.length-1];

        return Math.max(last,firsttwo);
    }

Answer (score -1):

**Python solution with 100% Score**

```
import sys
def solution(A):
    if len(A) < 3:
         return 0
    min_value = sys.maxsize*-1
    max_value = sys.maxsize
    positive_nus = [min_value]*3
    negative_nus =[max_value]*2


    for i in range(0,len(A)):
            if  A[i]> positive_nus[0]:
                positive_nus[2] = positive_nus[1]
                positive_nus[1]= positive_nus[0]
                positive_nus[0] = A[i]
            elif  A[i] > positive_nus[1]:
                positive_nus[2] = positive_nus[1]
                positive_nus[1]= A[i]
            elif  A[i] > positive_nus[2]:
                positive_nus[2] = A[i]
            if A[i] < negative_nus[0]:
                negative_nus[1] = negative_nus[0]
                negative_nus[0] = A[i]
            elif A[i] < negative_nus[1]:
                negative_nus[1] = A[i]

    sol1 = positive_nus[0]*positive_nus[1]*positive_nus[2]
    sol2 = positive_nus[0]*negative_nus[0]*negative_nus[1]
    return  max(sol1,sol2)
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript Solution from @Slobodan Antonijević Answer

```
function solution(A) {
    let N = A.length;
    /* some time sort doesn't work as expected try passing your own 
     sorting function to sort it in ascending order
    */
    A = A.sort((a,b) => (a-b));
    return Math.max(A[0] * A[1] * A[N - 1], A[N - 1] * A[N - 2] * A[N - 3]);
}
```

Comment: Title and body of the question ask about `without sorting`.

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone cares about C.
I tried quicksort before , but got 88% result due to performance issue.
So i ended up with an efficient (100%) yet messy code:
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingGT8RQR-FBM/

```
    int solution(int A[], int N) {


    int NEG[3]; NEG[0]=0; NEG[1] = 0; NEG[2]=0;    int p=-1;
    int POS[3]; POS[0] = 0; POS[1] =0; POS[2] = 0; int n=-1;
    int MAXIM[3]; MAXIM[0]=-1001; MAXIM[1]=-1001; MAXIM[2]=-1001; int m = -1;

    int i =0;

    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] < 0 && A[i] < NEG[2])
        {
            if(A[i] < NEG[0]) { NEG[2] = NEG[1]; NEG[1] = NEG[0];NEG[0] = A[i];}
            else if(A[i] < NEG[1]) { NEG[2] = NEG[1]; NEG[1] = A[i];}
            else if(A[i] < NEG[2]) NEG[2] = A[i];
            if(n < 2) n++;
        }        
        else if(A[i] >= 0 && A[i] > POS[2])
        {
        
            if(A[i] > POS[0]) {POS[2] = POS[1]; POS[1] = POS[0]; POS[0]=A[i];}
            else if(A[i] > POS[1]) {POS[2] = POS[1]; POS[1] = A[i];}
            else POS[2] = A[i]; 
            if(p < 2) p++;
        }

        if(A[i] <= 0 )
        {
        if(A[i] > MAXIM[0]){ MAXIM[2]=MAXIM[1];MAXIM[1]=MAXIM[0]; MAXIM[0]=A[i]; if(m<2)m++;}
        else if(A[i]>MAXIM[1]){MAXIM[2]=MAXIM[1]; MAXIM[1]=A[i];if(m<2)m++;}
        else if(A[i]>MAXIM[2]){MAXIM[2]=A[i]; if(m<2)m++;}
        
        
        }
    }

    int max =0, val_set =0;;
    if( n >=1 && p>=0 )
    {
        int tmp = NEG[0] * NEG[1] * POS[0];
        if(val_set == 0)
            { max = tmp;
                val_set =1;
            }
        else    
        if(tmp > max){
            max = tmp;
        } 
    }
    if( p > 1 )
    {
        int tmp = POS[0] * POS[1] * POS[2];
        if(val_set == 0)
            { max = tmp;
                val_set =1;
            }
        else
        if(tmp > max )
            {max = tmp;}
    } 
    else
    if( n > 1)
    {
        int tmp = NEG[0] * NEG[1] * NEG[2];
        if(val_set == 0)
            { max = tmp;
                val_set =1;
            }
        else
        if(tmp > max ){
            max = tmp;}
    }
    if(m>1){
    int temp = MAXIM[0] * MAXIM[1] * MAXIM[2];
           if(val_set == 0)
            { max = temp;
                val_set =1;
            }
        else if(temp > max){
        max = temp;}
    }  
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- **Sort** the array in Ascending order.
- Product1 = Product of **last 3 numbers** of the sorted array
- Product2 = Product of **last number and the first 2 numbers** of the sorted array
- Return the **maximum of two** above products

**O(n)** solution in **Javascript** could be:

```
function solution(A) {
    let sorted = A.sort((a, b) => a-b);
    let max1 = A[A.length - 1] * A[A.length - 2] * A[A.length - 3];
    let max2 = A[0] * A[1] * A[A.length - 1];
    
    return Math.max(max1, max2);
}
```